# Pypi performance test. Jmeter proxy returns error# 501

Tags: jmeter, pypi

I need to create an upload performance test for a custom Pypi repository. For this purpose I use the Jmeter recorder. I configured **.pypirc** file in my home directory and the system variables using

```
export https_proxy="http://myproxy.server.com:8080/"
```

then I extract files from tar.gz archive and run the command bellow

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r local
```

where local is taken from the .pypirc file however the proxy responded with

```
Upload failed (501): Method not implemented. error: Upload failed (501): Method not implemented
```

I also tried to upload tar.gz file using HTTP Request sampler without any success

```
"errors" : [ {"status" : 415, "message" : "Unsupported Media Type"  } ]
```

I used Content Type: application/x-tgz

What can be wrong in actions above?
Thanks.

Comment: Does it work without jmeter?

Comment: Yes, it does. I was able to upload whl and egg to the repo. I'm pretty sure that 501 error returns Jmeter proxy because when I run the upload command I receive the error however in the logs there is not any actions about it on the remote server, but have to an appropriate record in the logs